# ASPxUploadControl getting file size

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, devexpress

Is there a correct way to getting the file size when uploading an image with ASPxUploadControl? When the file is uploaded I would like to show the file size. So far I've not found out any sample code on how to do it via Google.

My current code:

VB.NET

```
<dxuc:ASPxUploadControl ID="ASPxUploadControl1" runat="server" ShowProgressPanel="True"
    ClientInstanceName="CompanyLogoUpload" FileUploadMode="OnPageLoad" ValidationSettings-GeneralErrorText="Upload Failed">
    <ClientSideEvents TextChanged="HandleFileInputTextChanged" FileUploadComplete="HandleFileUploadComplete" />
</dxuc:ASPxUploadControl>
```

ASP.NET

```
    function HandleFileUploadComplete(e, s)
    {
        var imgSrc = $("img[id$=CompanyLogoImage]").attr("src");
        $("img[id$=CompanyLogoImage]").attr("src", imgSrc + "1");
    }

    function HandleFileInputTextChanged(e, s) {
        $("input[id$=UseCompanyLogoCheckBox]").attr("checked", true);
        $("#ChangeLogoContainer").removeClass("overlay");
        CompanyLogoUpload.Upload();
   }
```

Comment: it looks like jQuery rather than ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/paulk/archive/2009/09/29/using-the-aspxuploadcontrol-and-displaying-image-thumbnails.aspx) shows how to wire up the client side events to show the thumbnail of the uploaded image.

```
<dxuc:ASPxUploadControl ID="ASPxUploadControl1" runat="server"  
                ClientInstanceName="uploader"  
                onfileuploadcomplete="ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete"> 
                <ClientSideEvents FileUploadComplete="function(s, e) { 
                  debugger; 
                  _aspxGetElementById('PreviewImage').src = e.callbackData; 
                }" /> 
            </dxuc:ASPxUploadControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

## **[Reference](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q237752.aspx)**

It is not possible to get the `File Size` due to `File Security`. You can do it in <kbd>PHP</kbd> easily but not in this tag.

It can be checked only at `server` side `Code Behind` code.

Comment: @MikhailPreyskurantov - can you share some sample code at client side. As I still doubt about it because the article is about sending large files.

Comment: There is no need to write code. Simply specify the corresponding validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to perform the client-side **[MaxFileSize](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxUploadControlValidationSettings_MaxFileSizetopic)** validation when using the “**Advanced Upload Mode**” only:

[Advanced Upload Mode > Client-Side Validation](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9886)